# Why when i try to get text in p tag with selenium its empty

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to get app id from p tag, I try whatever but output is empty

```py
p_tag = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")
p_tag = p_tag[1].text
print("_-_", p_tag)
```

Output:

```
_-_
```

Comment: Are you sure the second `p` element on the page contains text?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing a delay.
Try this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

p_tags = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "p")))
p_tag = p_tags[1].text
print("_-_", p_tag)
```